# Передать контекст в функцию jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я реально искал и на СО, и в Интернете, хоть заголовок вопроса везде один и тот же, но такой похожей ситуации, как у меня, я не встретил.
Хотя странно, ведь вопрос насущный должен быть для всех jQuery-вцев.

Есть такая структура:

```
var articles = $('article');

articles.click(function() {
    console.log(this);             // Выведется тот артикл, который кликнут
    articles.each(function() {
        console.log(this);         // Нужно вывести этот же артикл, который был кликнут
    });
});
```

Вместо вывода в консоль будет логика, само собой.
Но нужно понять, как ссылаться внутри функции в методе `.each` на тот артикл, который был кликнут, и при этом обойтись без переменных... Потому что тот this, который предоставляет метод `.each`, мне особо-то не нужен.

Такая ситуация у меня возникает не только тут, полезно было бы узнать, можно ли вообще передавать в эти функции свои аргументы.

Comment: Хотя ладно, `bind` сработал, поспешил я с вопросом.

Comment: Но можно и переменную `var article = this;` в замыкании завести.

Comment: @vp_arth, да с замыканием-то понятно, я думал есть какая-нибудь своя фича, чтобы в функции jquery передавать параметры извне, а её нет. Ну, в принципе-то, и зачем, если `bind` есть. Я про него не вспомнил просто.